# Cant remove Integer from Set

Tags: java, android, set

I have a problem with the line `m_schedules.get(0).getWeeklyScheduleSet().remove(day);`
I am unable to remove an `Integer`som a `Set<>`

The remove function returns true. The set returns true if i ask it if it contains the object. But it does not remove it at all. So i have no idea how to solve this.

```
private void setupToggleDays() {
        ViewGroup daysToggleHolder = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.activity_geofence_schedule_days_holder);
        m_daysToggleButtons = new ToggleButton[7];

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        int currWeekDayIndex = cal.getFirstDayOfWeek();

        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
          final int day = currWeekDayIndex;
          ToggleButton dayToggleButton = (ToggleButton) daysToggleHolder.getChildAt(i);
          m_daysToggleButtons[i] = dayToggleButton;
          dayToggleButton.setChecked(m_schedules.get(0).getWeeklyScheduleSet().contains(day));

          dayToggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
              if(isChecked){
                m_schedules.get(0).getWeeklyScheduleSet().add(day);
              }
              else {
                m_schedules.get(0).getWeeklyScheduleSet().remove(day);
              }
            }
          });
          currWeekDayIndex = (currWeekDayIndex % 7) + 1;
        }
      }
```

Comment: What kind of Collection does getWeeklyScheduleSet() return?

Comment: which collection you are checking whether element has been removed ?

Answer (score 2):

`day` is a local variable and you are removing value from Set on certain event, so `day` value will not be the value you have set it in a method. So try making day as field